# raising ValueError in a for loop

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyterhub

I am new to coding so bear with me. I am making a function that counts how many trues are in a list that is later defined. I also need a ValueError for incorrect input types. It also has to be a for loop. Please tell me what I am going wrong.

```
def only_true(bool_list):
    trues_count = 0
    for value in bool_list:
        if value == int or value == float:
            if value == True:
                trues_count = trues_count + 1   
        raise ValueError("values in list must be True or False")
    return trues_count
```

Comment: unintend the code lines, remove the `>` from each line. and replace single quote with a backtick ` - read more about [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting).

Comment: I think you need `type()`.

Answer (score 1):

Since `bool` is a subclass of `int`, you can simply add `value` to `true_count`. `True` will return `1` for arithmetic operations, whereas `False` will return `0`.

Remember also to first check that the type is a `bool`, and raise an error as needed.

```py
def only_true(bool_list: list):
    trues_count = 0

    for value in bool_list:
        if not isinstance(value, bool):
            raise ValueError("values in list must be True or False")

        trues_count += value

    return trues_count

print(only_true([False, False, True, False, True]))  # 2

# raises a ValueError
# only_true([1])
```

Below is a slightly different way of looking at it, where we check if `value` is `True` or `False` explicitly. If a value is not one of `(True, False)`, then it follows it is not a `bool`.

```py
def only_true(bool_list: list):
    trues_count = 0

    for value in bool_list:
        if value is True:
            trues_count += 1
        elif value is not False:
            # if a value is not True or False, then
            # by definition it is not a `bool`.
            raise ValueError("values in list must be True or False")

    return trues_count
```

Here is arguably a more "elegant" solution:

```py
def _handle_err(e):
    raise ValueError(f"{e!r}: values in list must be True or False, not {type(e).__name__}")


def only_true(bool_list: list):
    return sum(v if isinstance(v, bool) else _handle_err(v) for v in bool_list)
```

Lastly, this one liner will return the number of `True` (or truthy) values in a `list`, without explicitly checking that each element is a `bool` type.

```
only_true = sum
```

Comment: The second version makes a lot of sense, and uses things I've learned so far in my class. Thank you, it's good to see different ways to get the same outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is very close to correct. To determine the type of a variable you should use the `type()` function instead of comparing the value of the variable to a type such as `int` or `float`. In addition, I fixed your nested conditional so that we first check for a type mismatch then we check to see how many "trues" there are.

```
def only_true(bool_list):
    trues_count = 0
    for value in bool_list:
        if type(value) != bool:
            raise ValueError("values in list must be True or False")

        if value:
            trues_count = trues_count + 1   
        
    return trues_count

print(only_true([True, False, False, True]))
print(only_true([True, False, False, True, 1]))
```

Output

```
2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 13, in <module>
    print(only_true([True, False, False, True, 1]))
  File "test.py", line 5, in only_true
    raise ValueError("values in list must be True or False")
ValueError: values in list must be True or False
```